# How to enable verbose log for this node request module?

Tags: node.js, request

How to enable verbose log for the following node request module?

https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
 var reqParam = {
            'headers': {
                'User-Agent': 'CLA'
            },
            'body': 'CSCCDDSADADDADADADAAAEE', 
            'strictSSL': true,
            'jar': false,
            'encoding': null,
            'timeout': 300000
        };

  request.post(reqParam, function (err, res, body) {               
        if (err) {
           console.log('Curl request received an error:' + err);  
        }
    console.log(body);
  };
```

What is the option which will enable http VERBOSE log for the https://github.com/mikeal/request module ??

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Do you mean debug?

```
NODE_DEBUG=request node yourscript.js
```

Comment: NO. I mean debug log (curl verbose log)

Comment: There is no curl in request. Debug will dump the response status and headers though.

Comment: From the documentation: Set `require('request').debug = true` at any time ;)

Comment: @NicolasSiver This would be the answer, if it were an answer and not a comment. Thanks, it helped me.